# Make row occupy all the remaining space in html

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make row in twitter Bootstrap to occupy all the remaining space in the screen?

```
<.....html tags>
<>
....
<>
<div class="row" style="background-color:green">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

I want all the remaining space green based on above (The background will be green for any materials I have under this div, which is not what I want though).Now, in above case, I need the row to occupy all the space remaining in the screen? Is there some simple modification I can do to achieve this or I have to rely on javascript?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default margin or overwrite it.

```
.maxed{
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Then simply do:

```
<div class="container maxed">
    <div ...
    </div>
</div>
```

This ought to do it. Here's a bootply for the same: http://bootply.com/101394

A separate class ensures that your other containers aren't affected. Plus, as you see, this doesn't affect responsiveness.

Comment: @Ranvir: Some html would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have written  the above css assuming your row must be inside a container.

Comment: That being said, you are overriding the container class in CSS, right? Does that have any unnecessary side effects on layouts when used on various devices such as mobiles?

Comment: Nope, not at all. It works perfectly fine. Actually, for the mobile devices, I assume what they do is exactly the same by using `@media` tags. They just remove the margins. That way, you get a full width layout in mobile devices (no margins).

Comment: Ranveer: I tried your code and I think I made myself unclear. I have some-heading contents and other materials on top. Now I have one bottom section, for example, a game table, which I want to be green before anything happens. I want the particular div for green table( which comes at last of my html) to occupy all the remaining space FROM THAT POINT on. I don't want to modify any free space above.

Comment: Okay, so do one thing. Instead of overriding your `container` class, just make a new one and use it in the `div` where it is required.

Comment: I just added your code in above div as style="margin-right:0;margin-left:0;width:100%;background-color:green". I could not get the result I wanted.

Comment: Would you like to move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Okay, here is one thing you can do to show me my solution. Just create, two divs. One div, have a small paragraph with few words. Now in another div, make it TO OCCUPY ALL THE REMAINING SCREEN SPACE AFTER THE FIRST DIV (THIS IS IMPORTANT) and make it green. That would be it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43452/discussion-between-jack-of-all-trades-and-ranveer)